# Trigger zone not triggering

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TriggerZone : MonoBehaviour
{
    // This method is called when another collider enters the trigger zone.
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Debug.Log("WorkingIn");
        // Check if the colliding object is the player/MainCamera.
        if (other.CompareTag("Player") || other.CompareTag("MainCamera"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Player entered the trigger zone.");
            // Perform any actions or logic you want when the player enters the trigger zone.
        }
    }

    // This method is called when a collider exits the trigger zone.
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        Debug.Log("WorkingExit");
        // Check if the colliding object is the player/MainCamera.
        if (other.CompareTag("Player") || other.CompareTag("MainCamera"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Player exited the trigger zone.");
            // Perform any actions or logic you want when the player exits the trigger zone.
        }
    }
}
```

No matter what both the functions never get executed.
Although single gameobject is enough for collision but since it was not working i have added multiple.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does one of the [colliding GameObject have a RigidBody](https://discussions.unity.com/t/oncollisionenter-doesnt-work-without-rigidbody/9694)?

Comment: No, none of them, is Rigid body needed?

Comment: Yes, u are right, after adding Rigid body to the sphere collider object, its working, Initially it was working only once, so i figured out to disable gravity.
Please answer so i can mark it. And Thanks alot was doing since 3 hrs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Colliding GameObjects require a Rigidbody](https://discussions.unity.com/t/oncollisionenter-doesnt-work-without-rigidbody/9694). If you do not wish for collision to physically affect each other, you can just set [`isKinematic`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html) to true.